# Как добавить MouseEventHandler к PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, парсер, циклы, mouse-event

Собственно есть такой код, где в цикле создаются PictureBox

```
foreach (var pars in parsing)
            {
            var pn = new Panel();
            pn.Size = new Size(166, 260);
            flow.Controls.Add(pn);

            var lb = new Label();
            lb.Text = parsing[i].NameFilm;
            lb.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            lb.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 9.0f);
            lb.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
            pn.Controls.Add(lb);

            var hd = new Label();
            hd.Text = parsing[i].Quality;
            hd.Location = new Point (0,0);
            hd.Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 9.0f);
            hd.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
            //#c70016
            hd.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c70016");
            hd.Padding = new Padding(5,2,5,2);
            hd.AutoSize = true;
            pn.Controls.Add(hd);

            var pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            pb.Name = "pb" + i.ToString();                
            pb.Size = new Size(166, 246);
            pb.LoadAsync(parsing[i].ImageURl);
            pb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => Start(parsing[i].UrlFilm));
            pn.Controls.Add(pb);
            i++;
            }
```

Все хорошо работает, кроме
pb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => Start(parsing[i].UrlFilm));
При компиляции выдает ошибку о том, что "Индекс за пределами диапазона".

Если же вместо i написать [i-1]

```
pb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => Start(parsing[i-1].UrlFilm));
```

Тогда при нажатии на любой pictureBox будет открываться последний, в данном случае фильм.

Как же сделать так, чтоб каждому pictureBox присваивался свой MouseEventHandler?

Comment: попробуйте заменить `parsing[i-1]` на `pars`

Comment: вообще я бы создал новый класс наследуемый от `Panel` принимающий в конструкторе ваш `pars`.

Comment: @Monomax  Благодарю, глаза замылил..pb.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => Start(pars.UrlFilm));

Comment: @Monomax Вот так работает.

Comment: Можно оформить свой вариант как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего надо создать класс, наследуемый от Panel, не гоже использовать язык ООП и не применять ООП:

```
 class FilmPanel:Panel
 {
     public FilmPanel(ClassPars Pars, int PN)
     {
        Size = new Size(166, 260);
        Controls.Add(new Label{
           Text = Pars.NameFilm,
           Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
           Font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 9.0f),
           ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF"),
        });

        Controls.Add(new Label{
          Text = Pars.Quality,
          Location = new Point (0,0),
          ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF"),
          BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c70016"),
          Padding = new Padding(5,2,5,2),
          AutoSize = true
        });
        Controls.Add(FPB(Pars, PN));
     }

     PictureBox FPB((ClassPars Pars, int pn);
     {
         var res = new PictureBox{
          SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
          Dock = DockStyle.Top,
          Name = "pb" + pn,
          Size = new Size(166, 246)              
          };
          res.LoadAsync(Pars.ImageURl);
          res.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => Start(Pars.UrlFilm));
         return res;
     }

 }
```

а далее в коде пишется следующее:

```
 int i=0;
foreach (var pars in parsing)
{
     flow.Controls.Add(new FilmPanel(pars,i));
     i++;

}
```

Теперь код удобно читать, и легко править!

Comment: @SaDLiF надеюсь вам понравится моя идея.

Comment: в целом все работает, опять же кроме `res.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => Start(Pars.UrlFilm));` Дело в том, что метод Start Находится в классе формы. Даже если дать экземпляр класса `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` и использовать `res.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => form1.Start(Pars.UrlFilm));` То при клике мыши..ничего не происходит. Может я дурак и чего то не догоняю ")

Comment: @SaDLiF констатировать смерть пока еще рано, пациент уверено жив! Все просто, вам нужно метод Start, либо перенести в панель, либо в панели создать EventHandler, как поле.

Comment: дело в том, что метод Старт у меня работает непосредственно с формой. Даже если добавлять метод в панель, то всё равно мне надо обращаться из этого метода к форме. Собственно в этом и проблема ") Как сделать то по хорошему?")